# How to use ":host" (or ":host()") with ":has()"

Tags: css, web-component, custom-element

Does anybody know how to use `:host` (or `:host()`) with `:has()` ?

For example something like this:

```css
:host:has([disabled]) {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

or

```css
:host(:has([disabled])) {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

With the syntax from my example the `opacity` is not applied.

Comment: If ``disabled`` is an attribute on your Custom Element. It is ``:host([disabled])``

Comment: This would select an "host" element having the attribute "disabled", like so `<custom-element disabled />`, not an "host" having children with the attribute "disabled". Hence the need of the `:has()` function

Comment: ah so. AFAIK not possible, In this sence shadowRoots are like IFRAMEs

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, if you want to select a child of the pseudo-class `:host`. You can put a space between the two pseudo-classes as such `:host :has([disabled])`. It will select an element that is the child of `:host` and will have the `disabled` state.

Answer (score 0):

Can youse the `::slotted` but the caveat is it only selects direct children of your custom elements, i.e. not grand children and further.

```css
::slotted([disabled]) {
}
```